# How to load a Json link using webview and remove the HTML tags

Tags: android, json, webview

I have a Json URL am gettings from Wordpress, I want to display the text file using a Webview and format it, but I want to removed the HTMl tags also which display along with the text also.
This is the Json link.

```
   WebView newsfeed = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   try{                
       newsfeed.loadDataWithBaseURL("javascript:(function() { " +"url" +"})()", null, null, null, null);           
   }catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Try using stringtokenizer to remove the unwanted element

Comment: So... First of all, you have to learning json parsing and fetching data from that json you are getting. Can you please tell me which content you want from that json ?

Comment: @sharee202, the text between the tags, i want to use a webview, but remove the html tags and format the texts in paragraph

Comment: I am still not clear what is the data you are requiring from that json. See, your json contains "content" and "excerpt" keys. Are you talking about the same ?

Comment: @shree202, the content, its comes as a long content which i want to separate into different paragraph like this:- 1.., 2.., 3..

Comment: i want to remove the HTML tags and separate them into paragraph

Comment: heyy, did my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as per your requirement, your "content" will be obtained using:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.cepfonline.org/features/dyk/?json=1",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (result) {
                    // alert("success");

                    var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));

                    alert(obj.posts[0].content);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Above code will give you the data of "contents" key:

```
<p><span style=\"line-height: 1.5em;\">Did you know that our satellite TV Station, LoveWorld plus, can be viewed in over 50 countries of the world?</span></p>\n<p>Did you know that our ministry flagship programs are currently aired in over 180 Television stations worldwide?</p>\n<p>Did you know that through our LoveWorld Radio Ministry, our flagship programs air in over 200 countries across the world?</p>\n<div>Did you know that in the year 2013 alone, the Healing School hosted over 500 Ministers from 42 countries around the world through the Ministers’ visitation programme?</div>\n
```

Now, using [XML parser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp), you can get the core string data without html tags.

You can also do this, to strip the html tags. [Check this out](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/).

**Final answer:**

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.cepfonline.org/features/dyk/?json=1",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (result) {

                        var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));

                        var originalData = obj.posts[0].content;
                        var strippedData = originalData.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
                        alert(strippedData);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

    </html>
```